# Custom indentation for specific lines?

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

I currently try to figure out, how I can handle some lines specifically without messing up the indentation of the rest of the buffer. Consider the following function `MyFunc` as an example:

```
void MyFunc()
{
  unsigned y = 0;

DONOTINDENT;

  unsigned int x = 5 + 2;
  return x + 12;
}
```

Here, I want the line `DONOTINDENT;` to be indented to column 0, whereas the rest of the function should be indented normally. I tried to solve this using the following custom `c-special-indent-hook`:

```
(defun my-c-mode-indent-hook ()
  (let (p1 p2 myline)
    (setq p1 (line-beginning-position))
    (setq p2 (line-end-position))
    (setq myLine (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2))

    (if (string-match-p "DONOTINDENT" myLine)
        (save-excursion
          (indent-line-to 0))
      )
    )
  )

(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  ;; my customizations for all of c-mode and related modes
  (setq c-special-indent-hook 'my-c-mode-indent-hook)
  )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

OK, this works quite fine for the line `DONOTINDENT;`, however it does not work for all the subsequent lines, as these are indented relative to `DONOTINDENT;`. So, if `DONOTINDENT;` is indented to column 0, `unsigned int x = 5 + 2;` will be indented to column 0, too, but it should be indented to column `c-basic-offset`.

How can I fix up the indentation for the following lines? Is there some internal variable that I can use to influence the computation of the indent-level of the subsequent lines, or is this computation purely based on the preceding indentation. I think, it should be possible to somehow accomplish this as labels in switch-case-statements are indented in a similar way, but I struggled to figure this out when digging into the cc-mode code.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, depending on the nature of the DONOTINDENT line.

A custom [cc-offsets-alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#c_002doffsets_002dalist) rule allows different indentation rules depending on the syntactic element to indent. You could try to combine this with the correct [syntactic symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Syntactic-Symbols) to indent specific lines as you wish.